# How can I link this button and this action programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two simple classes at the moment, one being a container view controller and one a child view controller. I have an action inside the ContainerViewController.swift file, but it needs to be called in the HomeViewController.swift file. I obviously can't just call `ContainerViewController.presentDetailController(self)`, so how should I approach this?

**ContainerViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentDetailViewController: UIViewController?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    convenience init(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.init()

        currentDetailViewController = viewController
        self.presentDetailController(viewController)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var homeViewController: HomeViewController = HomeViewController.alloc()
        self.presentDetailController(homeViewController)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

    func presentDetailController(detailViewController: UIViewController) {
        if((self.currentDetailViewController) != nil) {
            self.removeCurrentDetailViewController();
        }

        self.addChildViewController(detailViewController)

        detailViewController.view.frame = self.frameForDetailController()

        self.view.addSubview(detailViewController.view)
        self.currentDetailViewController = detailViewController

        detailViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    func removeCurrentDetailViewController() {
        self.currentDetailViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        self.currentDetailViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.currentDetailViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    func frameForDetailController() -> CGRect {
        var detailFrame: CGRect = self.view.bounds

        return detailFrame
    }

}
```

**HomeViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    func initView () {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        var button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("ContainerViewController.presentDetailController(self)"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown) // This results in a fatal error!
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initView();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use delegate to pass message back to previous view controller from child view controller. [Reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274376/how-to-access-previous-view-elements-in-uinavigationcontroller). You can also get the view controller from navigation controller.

Comment: @zala Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Do you want to pass action back to parent controller from child controller?

Comment: @zala Yes, that's correct. I need to call 'presentDetailController' which is in ContainerViewController.swift from the HomeViewController.swift file.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can pass message back to parent view controller only by using delegation. There may be other ways but this is the only elegant way.

Method - 1

1)

Create a protocol and implement in your parent view controller

`@interface ParentController : UIViewController <NaviagationDelegate>`

```
@implementation ParentController
//implement method here
//{
// your action in parent controller
//}
```

2)

Now Create property in child controller with `NaviagationDelegate`

`@property (nonatomic, weak) id <NaviagationDelegate> navigationDelegate;`

Call the delegate method on event action of your child controller

```
    //Button action method
    {
        [self.navigationDelegate setText:@"action"];
    }
```

3)
Initialise the child controller's delegate property to self in parent view controller

```
prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ChildContoller class]])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setNavigationDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Method - 2

Just get the reference of the parent controller by checking all controllers from `self.navigationController.viewControllers` to parentController's class.

Comment: Implementation will be same just syntax changes for delegation. I hope you have done some code for that in swift as well.